# It is possible to link DBpedia to Protege?

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, dbpedia, protege

I need to link automatically the information from DBpedia to my own ontology.

Real scenario:

1. I created an individual (I can create a class also if necessary) of the country 'Austria'. I named it dbpedia:Austria (Protege recognize it as 'https://dbpedia.org/page/Austria').
2. Once created, I want to add in the Annotation tab the rdfs:label and dbo:abstract and I need the information to be filled automatically from 'https://dbpedia.org/page/Austria' (i.e. rdfs:label = Austria @en and dbo:abstract = Austria ( (), ; German: Österreich [ˈøːstɐʁaɪ̯ç] ()), officially the Republic of Austria (German: Republik Österreich, ), is a landlocked East Alpine country in the southern part of Central Europe. It is composed of nine federated states.......

Questions:

Is this possible? Do I have to create 'Austria' as an individual? or a class? the rdfs:label and dbo:abstract has to be in the Annotations Tab? Or object properties? or data properties?

Solution found:

It seems that TopBraid Composer (from TopQuadrant) has a feature which allows to link DBpedia information to the ontology automatically. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-KFEMzx0MY

However, I would like to use Protege if this is possible. TopBraid is not free.

Thanks,
Marius

Comment: that is not possible - nothing happens automatically in Protege nor in Linked Data in general. Always, tools and implementations have to follow the specifications. Indeed you could a) download the DBpedia data for a resource or b) write some Protege plugin that does what you need. Regarding class vs. individual, it's obviously an individual, there is only one Austria.

Comment: by the way, the URI is wrong, it is `https://dbpedia.org/resource/Austria` - `/page` is only the HTML represenation of the RDF data

Comment: @UninformedUser - Thank you! any guidelines for a) and b)? The DBpedia data can be downloaded in Protege? Also any tutorial on how can I write a Protege plugin to do what I need?

Comment: for each DBpedia resource you could easily download the data, the URL would be `https://dbpedia.org/resource/Austria.rdf` - but, you'll also need the DBpedia ontology aka schema because the OWL parser needs it to know the types of the proeprties, otherwise all data will be rendered as annotations which indeed is not intended. For plugins the Wiki should be your starting point: https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/PluginAnatomy - there is also already a minimal template to start with: https://github.com/stdotjohn/org.protege.plugin.template

Comment: @UninformedUser - I tried to figure out how to download the data for each resource and use the DBpedia ontology (schema) in order for OWL parser to know the types of properties but I couldn't do it. Could you indicate the steps in Protege for doing this? Thanks

Comment: download of the data has to be done separately. There is no functionality in Protege except for "loading from URL" as you might have noticed. But this is problematic as the DBpedia ontology would have to be merged with it before the parser does its job - and this isn't possible. The only way I see is to download the ontology and data besides Protege, then add it to your data.

Comment: @UninformedUser - Thank you for all your answers!